# Command doctrine:migrations:migrate error

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-migrations

I try to migrate my database, when I execute the command

```
php app/console doctrine:migrations:migrate xxxxxxxxxx
```

It results this message

```
Migration xxxxxxx was executed but did not result in any SQL statements.
```

Can Someone explain me thie message?

Comment: I would say this is because there is no SQL instruction in your migration file, but I cannot be sure without knowing its content. Can you copy/paste the content of your migration file here?

Comment: No, there is a sql instructions  

$this->addSql('CREATE TABLE axpLogger (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, user_id INT DEFAULT NULL, date DATETIME NOT NULL, status_code INT NOT NULL, page_uri VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, exception LONGTEXT NOT NULL, ip VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command execute up resolve the problem:

```
php app/console doctrine:migrations:execute xxxxxxxxxx up
```